# Using parameter tokens in IFNULL function in SQLite

Tags: python, api, sqlite

I am implementing a search function for my database.
For some search terms, the input might be null, so I'm using SQLite's `ifnull` function. Obviously, users might not input the perfect name, so I'm using LIKE to lookup (The other search terms are omitted here).
However, it seems that I'm using the wrong syntax.

This is my query:

```
args = (nameVar)
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM wines WHERE name LIKE IFNULL('%?%',name) COLLATE NOCASE", args)
```

This returns no results. However, if I instead use the python variables to build the string instead of using? for the parameters, it works perfectly.

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM wines WHERE name LIKE IFNULL('%"+nameVar+"%',name) COLLATE NOCASE")
```

This, however, is not a viable solution, as `nameVar` might be null which gives a string builder error.
Any help is appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQLite's concatenation operator `||` to concatenate the value of the `?` placeholder:

```
SELECT * 
FROM wines 
WHERE name 
LIKE IFNULL('%' || ? || '%', name)
```